# Several bathroom faucets leaking

Tags: plumbing

We have 1 shower head that continually leaks and in another bathroom the tub faucet leaks. A pressure relief valve was placed on the house. We switched Moen cartridges twice. We tried adjusting PRV went all the way down to 20 psi and it still leaks.

Initially the house didn't have a PRV and when it was first installed, the leaking stopped but only for a few weeks and then came back in the same manner as it appeared. Slow drips that increase to a constant leak. What could be the problem?

Comment: How old are the fixtures (or the house)?  How much/fast do they leak?  How did you try to repair the fixtures themselves?

Comment: What was the pressure before the PRV? Do you get a lot of calcium buildup in your fixtures?

Comment: Bodies could be damaged which would prevent new cartridges from holding up and keeping things sealed.  Design could be faulty;  some faucets the manufacturers just messed up on and a prone to leakes and caryridge replacements.  Both of these things are rather rare but it sounds like you have extenuating circumstances.

Comment: @isherwood I have a question related to your comment here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/137696/multiple-leaking-faucets-after-a-hotwater-tank-and-prv-install-any-tricks